# How to delete duplicated rows with the same day?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

My table looks like:

```
id      name        value       date
1       John        25      2013-03-23 16:42:35
2       John        25      2013-03-23 13:52:24
3       John        26      2013-03-22 03:12:43
4       Gabriel     18      2013-03-23 10:21:07
5       Rick        32      2013-03-21 04:37:29
```

How to remove the rows with the same `name` and the timestamp `date` with the same day? For example, the table above should be:

```
id      name        value       date
1       John        25      2013-03-23 16:42:35
3       John        26      2013-03-22 03:12:43
4       Gabriel     18      2013-03-23 10:21:07
5       Rick        32      2013-03-21 04:37:29
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. One is by using a subquery which gets one record of name in each day and the result of the subquery is then joined back on the table. The non matching rows will then be filtered and deleted.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name, date(date) dateOnly, MIN(ID) min_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY name, date(date)
        ) b ON  a.name = b.name AND
                Date(a.date) = b.dateonly AND
                a.ID = b.min_ID
WHERE   b.name IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdf84/1)

Comment: Could you explain me the `WHERE   b.name IS NULL` part? Thank you!